# How do I reverse results of a table row with Javascript from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I'd like to be able to reverse the results of a table returned from a PHP database with javascript, but can't seem to figure out how to get the reverse(); method to work. I'd appreciate any help you could give me.

This is my Javascript:

```
function title()
{
var sortedOn = 0;
var display = document.getElementById("table");
var list = new Array();
var tableLength = display.rows.length;
    for(var i = 1; i < tableLength; i++){
var row = display.rows[i];
var info = row.cells[0].textContent;
    list.push([info,row]);
}

list.sort();

var listLength = list.length;

for(var i = 0; i < listLength; i++) {
display.appendChild(list[i][1]);
}
```

This is in my html table:

```
    <th><a href="javascript:;" onclick="title();">Title</a></th>
```

Comment: list.sort(); becomes list.sort().reverse();

Comment: Thanks, that works. But I'd like to be able to reverse the order when a user clicks on the table heading. So the list will reverse on each click.

Comment: then you need to pass the col# instead of hard-coding 0, and you need to keep track of all the column flips. an array of booleans works well, ex: if(flip[3]=!flip[3]) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function reverse(){
    var display = document.getElementById("table");
    var length = display.rows.length;

    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        display.appendChild(
            display.removeChild(display.rows[length - i - 1])
        );

    }
}
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sXW29/)

Comment: Thanks, but that scrolls the list towards the top of the page with each onclick. I'd like the whole array to be in reverse order with one click.  Alphabetical order or reverse-alphabetical order.